# UIButton Background image resizes

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, background, uibutton

I'm working on a project where my `UIButtons` will have a custom background image. I'm currently only testing on the iPhone 6 Plus so the images have the sizes to match that resolution.

The image has the exact size of the button which is 414 x 226, however the iPhone still resizes, or well zoom in the image when I run it in the simulator.
[image]

That's a picture from the Interface builder / Inspector showing the issue.

Any idea on how I can fix this?

Comment: Hi, check out my answer... if it doesn't help you leave me a comment...

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the content mode of UIButton to Scale to fill. And if you are comfortable with Autolayout, use constraints to set the position of UIButton (and fix the height, if thats what you want) and other components in your view. I believe with constraints properly set, it should not resize in runtime.

Comment: The content mode is already set to Scale to fill. I'm still learning autolayout but me and it aren't getting so good along yet. I miss the good old days when you only hade one screensize fo worry about! When I came back to iOS development after a few years in C# it just made me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set this on your Button...

```
myButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

**Update**

please try this...

```
myButton.imageView?.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: ok, can I see some code? The part where you assign the image to the Button?

Comment: The button is actually set directly in the interface builder / inspector.

Comment: Ok, than please shortly try my update... maybe you need to set the buttons image views layer to masktobounds = true

Comment: Tried that one too now, doesn't seem to work either I'm afraid.